# How to write an image with index 10 stored in a folder using list

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, glob

How do I retrieve or write an image with list index 10 using OpenCV, Python

```
filenames = [img for img in glob.glob("./Testing/2019*.jpg")
filenames.sort

cv2.imwrite("img.jpg", filenames[10])
```

It returns the error:

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

How can I retrieve an image with a particular index value from a list and save it

Comment: You need to pass the array containing the pixels of the image to `imwrite()` - not just the filename. You haven't loaded the images.

Comment: To expand Mark's comment: To load the image, you'd need something like `img = cv2.imread(filenames[10])`. Then, `img` is the mentioned NumPy array containing the image data. To write the image, you can then use `cv2.imwrite("img.jpg", img)`.

Comment: @HansHirse got it